Solving Geometry Error in LST Prediction Using QGIS and MOLUSCE Plugin
I’m currently working on a project to predict Land Surface Temperature (LST) for the year 2033 using QGIS and the MOLUSCE plugin. My dataset includes LST raster layers for 2013 and 2023, along with spatial variables like NDWI and NDVI.
However, I’ve hit a roadblock with the following error message: “Geometries of the initial raster and raster are different!”
I’ve double-checked to ensure that all my layers are in the same coordinate system, but the issue persists.
How can I ensure all geometries align properly in QGIS so that I can make the prediction map?

Check the columns and rows of your layers and ensure they all match.
The easiest way is to view your layers on a GIS platform like ArcMap >>go to properties of one layer >> source

To match geometries of layers; choose one layer and copy its extents use this extents as clipping extents for the rest of your layers preferably in QGIS
e.g.  using the extents of chosen layer to clip all the other layers

Ensure you maintain the extents all through the other layers
to verify if geometry is correct check the properties of each layer, the columns and rows should now be equal
That's all.
